# Creating advanced candlestick charts with HTML5 and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts

I have an array of data from a stock (open, high, low, close, volume). My goal is to produce a candlestick chart similar to the one below.

[image]

The issue is, I have no idea how to translate this raw data into a presentable and interactive format. I'm sure I can draw a candlestick using CSS, but that does not handle the problem of zooming or plotting it correctly.

Comment: There are numerous charting libraries that generate candlestick charts

Answer (score 1):

Use a CDN library like ***plotly js*** https://plotly.com/javascript/